# Is there a way to sort a list of two element tuples by both elements, but one of the elements reverse sorted?

Tags: python, sorting, tuples

I want to sort a list of tuples (the tuples have the format (integer, string)) so that they are ordered from greatest to least integer and then the strings are sorted alphabetically without losing the integer order.

```
### Inputs: data = [(86, 'william'), (74, 'olivia'), (86, 'willaim'), (62, 'lyli'), (74, 'olivai'), (62, 'lily')]
### Outputs: data = [(86, 'willaim'), (86, 'william'), (74, 'olivai'), (74, 'olivia'), (62, 'lily'), (62, 'lyli')]
### What I know how to do: I know how to sort the tuples by specific element from greatest to least
import operator
data.sort(key = operator.itemgetter(0), reverse = True)
### This returns:
### data = [(86, 'william'), (86, 'willaim'), (74, 'olivia'), (74, 'olivai'), (62, 'lily'), (62, 'lyli')]
### At this point I'm not sure how to keep the integers ordered while sorting the strings alphabetically
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34009982/5277295 try this one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data.sort(key=lambda x: (-x[0], x[1]))
```

If your key is a tuple, the sorting algorithm will prioritize sorting according to the first element of the tuple, then the second and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Python's `sort` [is stable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort):

> The `sort()` method is guaranteed to be stable. A sort is stable if it guarantees not to change the relative order of elements that compare equal — this is helpful for sorting in multiple passes (for example, sort by department, then by salary grade).

So you can sort by the strings *first*, and then by the integers. This leaves the integers in descending order, but any items with the same integer will stay in the same relative order from when they were sorted by the strings.

```py
from operator import itemgetter

data.sort(key=itemgetter(1))
data.sort(key=itemgetter(0), reverse=True)
```

This is not as efficient as Mikhail Genkin's answer, but it's closer to what you were trying to do.